# writing to a text file

Tags: php

I have a form that write its values to a text file. My problem is that when a user submits a form it over writes the value from the last users submission. What changes would i need to make in order to have it record each users submission and not over write it each time.

```
// This just names the file
$target_filename = "usersubmit_f456sd4f56sd4f.txt";

// Create an empty buffer
$message = "";

// This gets all the form keys (names) and values
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
$message .= "$key: $value\n";

// Put the date in
$message .= date("F j, Y, g:i a");

// Open the file and write it out
$fp = @fopen($target_filename,"wt");
if ($fp != NULL) 
{
fputs($fp,$message);
fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
$fp = @fopen($target_filename,"wt");
```

TO

```
$fp = fopen($target_filename, 'a');
```

You can find references [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)... When using `a` it means to append... When file doesn't exists this function will force creation...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
<?php 
    $target_filename = "testFile.txt";
    $fh = fopen($target_filename, 'r');
    $theData = fread($fh, filesize($target_filename));

    $fh = fopen($target_filename, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $message = $theData."\n";
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    $message .= "$key: $value\n";

    //Put the date in
    $message .= date("F j, Y, g:i a");
    fwrite($fh, $message);
    fclose($fh);
    ?>
```

Hope it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try instead

```
<?php
$file = 'usersubmit_f456sd4f56sd4f.txt';
// The new person to add to the file
 $person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
?>
```

[file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

> This function is identical to calling `fopen()`, `fwrite()` and `fclose()` successively to write data to a file

Comment: LOCK_EX will be a problem if more than one instance is running. But thats a general problem for this task.

Comment: @fender, that i mentioned already in comment lines, see the answer again please

Comment: I have seen it. I just wanted to make it a bit clearer. I am sure you know it, so this info was for sarsar, but it looks like his script is just for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in ***a**ppend* mode:

```
$fp = fopen($target_filename, 'a');
```

You could also simply use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents):

```
file_put_contents($target_filename, $message, FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0):

take this [fopen() function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp) or You can Go with [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) ......use this

```
// This just names the file
$target_filename = "usersubmit_f456sd4f56sd4f.txt";

// Create an empty buffer
$message = "";

// This gets all the form keys (names) and values
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
$message .= "$key: $value\n";

// Put the date in
$message .= date("F j, Y, g:i a");

// Open the file and write it out
$fp = fopen($target_filename, 'a'); 
if ($fp != NULL) 
{
fputs($fp,$message);
fclose($fp);
}
```

`a`:    `Append`. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist

```
Modes   Description
r   Read only. Starts at the beginning of the file
r+  Read/Write. Starts at the beginning of the file
w   Write only. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist
w+  Read/Write. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist
a   Append. Opens and writes to the end of the file or creates a new file if it doesn't exist
a+  Read/Append. Preserves file content by writing to the end of the file
x   Write only. Creates a new file. Returns FALSE and an error if file already exists
x+  Read/Write. Creates a new file. Returns FALSE and an error if file already
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// Open the file and write it out
$fp = @fopen($target_filename,"wt");
if ($fp != NULL) 
{
    fseek($fp,0,SEEK_END);
    fputs($fp,$message);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

http://php.net/fseek